# Covariant Derivative with a Torsion Free Metric

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

Where $\triangledown$ is the covariant derivative and we are to assume that the connection is torsion free (that is, we can exchange the lower indices of the connection coefficients), how can I prove the following identity?

$$
X^b\partial_bY^a-Y^b\partial_bX^a=X^b(\triangledown_{{\partial}_b}\overrightarrow{Y})^a-Y^b(\triangledown_{{\partial}_b}\overrightarrow{X})^a
$$

I am struggling quite a bit with this. If anyone has any input on how to show this, please let me know.

Comment: Let me make sure the notation. Why do you add $\vec{}$ on the RHS, but not LHS?

Comment: Show some of your work.

Comment: If torsion is defined as $T(X,Y) = \nabla_XY-\nabla_YX-[X,Y]$, then the identity follows from $T(X,Y) = 0$ immediately. If both the torsion and the covariant derivative are defined in terms of connection coefficients, then it's just straightforward substitution those definitions. I think you're going to have to clarify your difficulty.

Comment: It turns out it was that straightforward, and I just trying to prove it using the wrong principles. Thanks for the comments anyway.
To clarify, the vector arrows on the right side are because the covariant derivative there is operating on the vector, and then we are taking the a-th component of the result. On the left, the partial derivatives are operating on components.